# Access the previous element inside the function of for_each

Tags: c++, list, c++17

I'm trying to implement the fibonacci sequence in C++17 using `for_each`

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 
  list<int> mylist = {1,2,3,4,5};
  for_each( next(mylist.begin()), mylist.end(), [](int &n){n = n + prev(n);});
}
```

to access the previous element inside the function, `prev` doesn't work. How can I access the previous element inside the function? Thanks.

Comment: `n` is an `int` inside the lambda, so `prev(n)` makes no sense.

Comment: What is the expected result? And why use `std::list` instead of `std::vector`? This is almost never what you want.

Comment: Use [`std::adjacent_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) instead.  The link even has an example of it computing the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use `std::list`.  It has terrible performance, even if it is algorithmically better.  `std::vector` should be your go-to container unless you need an associative container.

Comment: @Holt of course I know the `prev(n)` won't work. It's basically there to describe the problem. @Konrad Rudolph, the expected result is of course to generate a fibonacci sequence. I've chosen the `std::list` just to describe the problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver I've chosen the `std::list` basically by its name, i.e. it  sounds more intuitive. The code is just for exercise purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's much simpler to use `std::adjacent_difference` for operations on consecutive elements.

If you really want to improve your understanding of `std::for_each`, then it's possible, but you will have to take responsibility for updating a shadow iterator yourself, as it's not possible to work back from an element to an iterator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> v(15);
    v.front() = 1;

    auto it = v.begin();
    auto prev = it;
    auto current = *it++;
    std::for_each(it, v.end(),
             [&current,&prev](int& n){ std::swap(n, current); current = n+*prev++;});

    for (auto n: v) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

However, if we use `std::vector` for our storage, then we do have a way to access the previous element, since vectors store their elements contiguously:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(15);
    v[0] = v[1] = 1;

    std::for_each(v.begin()+2, v.end(),
             [](int& n){ n = (&n)[-1] + (&n)[-2];});

    for (auto n: v) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `v[0] = 0; v[1] = 1;` ?

Comment: @Ted - that depends on whether you want a Fibonacci sequence that starts from 0 or from 1.

Comment: It just felt cruel to poor `0` to leave it out of the sequence, but I guess there is an infinite number of larger values that will be left out too.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could use `prev` to access the previous element, it's unclear how the posted algorithm would generate the expected result (a Fibonacci sequence), because the passed list is initialized as

```
list<int> mylist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

The lambda would have added (if it worked) the value of the previous element (already modified!) to the **current** one, resulting in the sequence: 1, 2 + **1** = **3**, 3 + **3** = 6, ...

It may be easier to use a stateful lambda and a different algorithm, like `std::generate` (or `std::generate_n`).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
auto make_fibonacci_generator(T first, T second)
{
    return [prev = first, cur = second] () mutable {
        return cur += std::exchange(prev, cur);
    };
}

template <class OutIt, class T = typename OutIt::value_type>
auto gen_n_fibonacci_numbers(T first, T second, std::size_t n, OutIt dest)
{
    if ( n == std::size_t(0) )
        return dest;
    *dest++ = first;
    if ( n == std::size_t(1) )
        return dest;
    *dest++ = second;
    if ( n == std::size_t(2) )
        return dest;
    return std::generate_n(dest, n - 2, make_fibonacci_generator(first, second));
}


template <class OutIt, class T = typename OutIt::value_type>
void gen_fibonacci_numbers(T first, T second, OutIt dest, OutIt dest_last)
{
    if ( dest == dest_last )
        return;
    *dest++ = first;
    if ( dest == dest_last )
        return;
    *dest++ = second;
    if ( dest == dest_last )
        return;
    std::generate(dest, dest_last, make_fibonacci_generator(first, second));
}


int main()
{
    std::list<unsigned int> numbers;
    gen_n_fibonacci_numbers(0, 1, 20, std::back_inserter(numbers));


    for (auto i : numbers)
        std::cout << ' ' << i;
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::array<int, 10> nums;
    gen_fibonacci_numbers(0, 1, nums.begin(), nums.end());

    for (auto i : nums)
        std::cout << ' ' << i;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8jaMQ9foALYAZLp4).